# Batch change form data in adobe acrobat

Tags: javascript, adobe, batch-processing, acrobat

I have a form in adobe acrobat that has been filled out. It's about 30 different forms but all have the same information. I need to update the address on each form and change the name of the person who edited the document. I know in other adobe products I could record a process but that isn't offered in acrobat. I was reading about using javascript but I am not too familiar with it. How can I make a script to change the name, address, and date of the form?

Comment: Note that [tag:batch-file] does not mean processing many files.

Comment: I you aren't intending to create your script as a .bat file, you should remove the batch-file tag from your question.

Comment: I swear correcting "batch-file" to "batch-processing" is my most common edit...

Comment: I don’t care to change each file one by one but I just don’t want to have to type each stupid field. As I open the file I want to run a script that corrects the data in each one.